# Sort rows to match multiple columns in another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have been trying to sort the rows of my dataset(A2) to match multiple columns of another dataset (A1). I used a code sometime back and it worked perfectly. Today I modified the code to use on a new data set and I am getting NA's which I shouldn't be getting.

This is the code I am using

```
A4 <- A2[match(paste(A1$Subject,A1$Condition,A1$test, A1$Replication), paste(A2$Subject,A2$Condition,A2$test,A2$Replication)),]
```

Data:

```
A1 <- structure(list(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), Condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2), test = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2), Replication = c(101, 108, 103, 105, 101, 108, 103, 
105, 101, 108, 103, 105, 101, 108, 103, 105), Movement = c(43, 
56, 45, 43, 35, 34, 34, 3, 4, 67, 45, 34, 65, 34, 345, 23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


A2 <-structure(list(Subject = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), test = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Replication = c(108, 101, 103, 105, 101, 108, 
103, 105, 108, 101, 103, 105, 101, 108, 103, 105), Movement = c(43, 
56, 45, 43, 35, 34, 34, 3, 4, 67, 45, 34, 65, 34, 345, 23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data frame for ```A2``` and ```A4``` with ```dput()```? It will make the job easier for everyone.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb, I jut added some data thanks

Comment: You are getting `NA`'s because certain combination of rows is not present in `A2`. For example, see row 5 in `A1` has no match in `A2`. What is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you, I went back to my data based on your comment and fixed it

Answer (score 1):

We may use `slice` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
A2 %>% 
   slice(match(invoke(str_c, across(Subject:Replication,  ~ 
     A1[[cur_column()]])), invoke(str_c, across(Subject:Replication))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 5
   Subject Condition  test Replication Movement
     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       1         1     1         101       67
 2       1         1     1         108        4
 3       1         2     1         103       45
 4       1         2     1         105       34
 5       1         1     2         108       34
 6       1         2     2         105       23
 7       2         1     1         101       56
 8       2         1     1         108       43
 9       2         2     1         103       45
10       2         2     1         105       43
11       2         1     2         101       35
12       2         1     2         108       34
13       2         2     2         103       34
14       2         2     2         105        3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `merge`

```r
join_vars <- c('Subject', 'Condition', 'test', 'Replication')

merge(A2, A1[, join_vars], by = join_vars, all.x = FALSE)

#>    Subject Condition test Replication Movement
#> 1        1         1    1         101       67
#> 2        1         1    1         108        4
#> 3        1         1    2         108       34
#> 4        1         2    1         103       45
#> 5        1         2    1         105       34
#> 6        1         2    2         105       23
#> 7        2         1    1         101       56
#> 8        2         1    1         108       43
#> 9        2         1    2         101       35
#> 10       2         1    2         108       34
#> 11       2         2    1         103       45
#> 12       2         2    1         105       43
#> 13       2         2    2         103       34
#> 14       2         2    2         105        3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may use `na.omit`, also `Reduce` makes life easier.

```
A2[na.omit(match(Reduce(paste, A1[-5]), Reduce(paste, A2[-5]))), ]
#    Subject Condition test Replication Movement
# 10       1         1    1         101       67
# 9        1         1    1         108        4
# 11       1         2    1         103       45
# 12       1         2    1         105       34
# 14       1         1    2         108       34
# 16       1         2    2         105       23
# 2        2         1    1         101       56
# 1        2         1    1         108       43
# 3        2         2    1         103       45
# 4        2         2    1         105       43
# 5        2         1    2         101       35
# 6        2         1    2         108       34
# 7        2         2    2         103       34
# 8        2         2    2         105        3
```